# directive for highlighting selected text in response using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angularjs.what is the directive to highlight the text that we are searching in angularjs. 
for example:
if I am entering a text "ABC" in the search box then in response where ever it is present, it should highlight.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean searching off of a QueryString parameter?

Answer (score 0):

If am get you right here is what you are looking for

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {

});

myApp.directive('searchColor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {          
           element.css('color', 'red');                                
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="t" search-color placeholder="type something here"/>
</div>
```